# How do I open a specific form based on the user input in a text box (MS Access)?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

Just for some context: I am using MS Access 2016.

I have 3 dashboard forms for 3 types of employees (employees, managers, contractors). Each type of employee has a separate table and everyone has a unique ID. Managers will have an employeeID AND a managerID.

I have a form that I will have people start with. It will have a text box asking for the users ID number and a button that says "Go to Dashboard".

Depending on the type of employee that ID number belongs to, I want the correct dashboard form to open.

So let's say I am a manager and I enter my manager ID and click go.. I will be taken to the Manager Dashboard. If I enter my employee ID and click go.. I will be taken to the Employee Dashboard.

Not sure how do do this.. I'd like to do it with the expression builder if possible.

Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: Please give us more information about your database design.

Comment: Better share a sample (With dummy data) file, so that we can code in it.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep a Table with 3 fields to store the Employee Id and Password along with the Form name they can access.

Use DLookup() function to do the comparison against the table to check the User ID and Password credentials.  If it matches with the Textbox entry then use the Same DLookup() function to get the form name from that table and populate the form to the employee.